# ionic 2 project reports 97% coverage but sonar reports 0% coverage

Tags: node.js, ionic2, sonarqube, jestjs

I'm trying to integrate an ionic project with sonar, and everything seems to be OK but the coverage, tests are developed with jest and the `test:coverage` task (`jest --coverage`) is reporting a 97% but I get a 0 coverage in sonar.

npm run test:coverage result:

```
Test Suites: 5 passed, 5 total
Tests:       14 passed, 14 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.004s
Ran all test suites.
-----------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File                               |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
-----------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files                          |    97.53 |       75 |    84.85 |    97.22 |                |
 app                               |      100 |    76.92 |      100 |      100 |                |
  app.component.ts                 |      100 |    76.92 |      100 |      100 |             14 |
  app.html                         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
 pages/appointment                 |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
  appointment.module.ts            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
 pages/appointment/appointmentItem |      100 |    76.92 |      100 |      100 |                |
  appointmentItemPage.html         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
  appointmentItemPage.ts           |      100 |    76.92 |      100 |      100 |          17,18 |
 pages/appointment/appointmentList |    94.12 |       75 |       80 |    93.33 |                |
  appointmentListPage.html         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
  appointmentListPage.ts           |    93.75 |       75 |       80 |    92.86 |             32 |
 pages/home                        |    85.71 |    66.67 |    66.67 |    83.33 |                |
  home.html                        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
  home.ts                          |    83.33 |    66.67 |    66.67 |       80 |             16 |
 providers/appointment             |      100 |    66.67 |    83.33 |      100 |                |
  appointmentData.ts               |      100 |      100 |    83.33 |      100 |                |
  appointmentProvider.ts           |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |      100 |             21 |
  prospectData.ts                  |      100 |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |                |
-----------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

The coverage/lcov.info it's been correctly generated (abstract of a file):

```
TN:
SF:/home/jmgomez/securitas/sst/src/app/app.component.ts
FN:11,(anonymous_2)
FN:14,MyApp
FN:15,(anonymous_4)
FNF:3
FNH:3
FNDA:1,(anonymous_2)
FNDA:1,MyApp
FNDA:1,(anonymous_4)
DA:11,1
DA:12,1
DA:15,1
DA:18,1
DA:19,1
DA:22,1
LF:6
LH:6
BRDA:14,0,0,1
BRDA:14,0,1,0
BRDA:14,1,0,1
BRDA:14,2,0,1
BRDA:14,2,1,1
BRDA:14,2,2,0
BRDA:14,3,0,1
BRDA:14,3,1,1
BRDA:14,4,0,1
BRDA:14,4,1,1
BRDA:14,4,2,0
BRDA:14,5,0,1
BRDA:14,5,1,1
BRF:13
BRH:10
end_of_record
```

And linked into the sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=sst:app
sonar.projectName=sst_app
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=./src/
sonar.tests=.
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

This is the listing for the coverage folder

```
ls coverage/ -la
total 36
drwxrwxr-x  3 myuser mygroup  4096 ene  3 12:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 myuser mygroup  4096 ene  3 11:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser mygroup 19778 ene  3 11:57 coverage-final.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser mygroup  4032 ene  3 11:57 lcov.info
drwxrwxr-x  7 myuser mygroup  4096 dic 20 15:27 lcov-report
```

Related log lines for sonnar-scanner command are the following:

```
INFO: Excluded sources: 
INFO:   **/*.spec.ts
INFO: Included tests: 
INFO:   **/*.spec.ts
INFO: 35 files indexed
...
INFO: Sensor TypeScript LCOV Coverage Sensor [typescript]
INFO: Sensor TypeScript LCOV Coverage Sensor [typescript] (done) | time=4ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript Squid Sensor [javascript]
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Test Coverage Sensor is started
INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Analysing [/home/jmgomez/securitas/sst/coverage/lcov.info]
INFO: Sensor JavaScript Squid Sensor [javascript] (done) | time=135ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=29ms
```

Any hint?, Am I missing something?

Comment: Whenever I ran into this problem it was almost always caused by case sensitivity in the file paths. Could this be your issue? If the path names on disk and in the coverage file are not exactly the same sonar gets confused. Example: `app` in the coverage file and `App` on disk will not work.

Comment: @tehbeardedone I checked all the folder and file names and everything is correct, but you make me think about the property sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths and I notice that I was using javascript instead of typescript, so once modified the language, everything is working like charm :-)

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.